# Apply css to button element with certain class

Tags: css

bluebutton.css

```
.btnBlue button{
Styles go here
}

.btnBlue button::-moz-focus-inner{
Styles go here
}

.btnBlue button:hover,button:focus{
styles go here
}

.btnBlue button:active{
Styles go here
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Css buttons</title>
<link type='text/css' href='css/bluebutton.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />
</head>
<body>
<button type="submit" class="btnBlue">Okay</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This does not seem to work. I know it works if i try to do it without the .btnBlue but i want to create different button styles. So like i can define for each button what style to use.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Think you need to change the stylesheet declarations here to:

```
button.btnBlue {
  /* Styles go here */
}

button::-moz-focus-inner.btnBlue {
  /* Styles go here */
}

button:hover.btnBlue,
button:focus.btnBlue {
  /* Styles go here */
}

button:active.btnBlue {
  /* Styles go here */
}
```